# using .read() and .readlines() but it only returns a list

Tags: python

```
with open("test.txt", 'r') as file_read:
    contents_list = file_read.readlines() # gives list with each line as a item
    print(contents_list)
    contents_og = file_read.read() # reads it as it is
    print(contents_og)
```

with this code, it only prints this

```
['1) First\n', '2) Second\n', '3) Third\n', '4) Fourth\n', '5) Fifth\n', '6) Sixth\n', '7) Seventh\n', '8) Eigth\n', '9) Nineth\n', '10) Tenth']
```

although I expect also this with the list:

```
1) First
2) Second
3) Third
4) Fourth
5) Fifth
6) Sixth
7) Seventh
8) Eigth
9) Nineth
10) Tenth
```

why does it not print both?

Comment: You've already read the entire file by calling `file_read.readlines()`, your `file_read.read()` have nothing left to read. A quick workaround would be calling`file_read.seek(0, 0)` between the former and the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show what the test.txt file looks like?
it should look something like this

```
with open("test.txt", 'r') as file_read:
    contents_list = file_read.readlines() # gives list with each line as a item
    print(contents_list)
    contents_og = file_read.read() # reads it as it is
    for item in contents_og:
        remove = item.count("\n")
        if remove >= 0:
            item.replace("\n","")
            print(item)
```

to print it in the format you want, you must loop through the items, i would have been able to write the exact code you needed, however i do not know what your txt file looks like.